# service status keyword "service" is not needed

Tags: sudo, path, services, cd-command

Could somebody help me understand why the following is happening?

```
$ cd /etc/init.d; sudo service hadoop-hdfs-namenode status
Hadoop namenode is running [ OK ]

$ sudo /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-namenode status
Hadoop namenode is running [ OK ]

$ sudo service /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-namenode status
/etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-namenode: unrecognized service

$ cd /etc/init.d; sudo hadoop-hdfs-namenode status
sudo: hadoop-hdfs-namenode: command not found
```

Basically, I found if I am in `/etc/init.d/`, `service` must be added before `hadoop-hdfs-namenode` to make it run, otherwise the `command not found` error will be generated.

But if I am in the home directory, it is OK not to add `service`, and actually, adding `service` anywhere will always be wrong.

Why is `service` not needed and adding it will always be wrong when I am in the home directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally `.` is not on your path.  So you need to specify the path to the script to run.  If that is the current directory then:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ cd /etc/init.d; sudo ./hadoop-hdfs-namenode status
```

As to `service`, you should not need to specify a path in front of the service name. This should work fine:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sudo service hadoop-hdfs-namenode status
```